# optimizing multiple if statements

Tags: javascript

I have some code that looks like this:

```
TheClass = TheAjaxIndicator.prop('class');

if (TheClass.indexOf('Blue') > 0) { TheHTML = TheHTMLBlue; }
if (TheClass.indexOf('White') > 0) { TheHTML = TheHTMLWhite; }
if (TheClass.indexOf('Green') > 0) { TheHTML = TheHTMLGreen; }
if (TheClass.indexOf('Brown') > 0) { TheHTML = TheHTMLBrown; }
```

How  can I avoid all these `if` statements?

Thanks.

Comment: What are possible values of `TheClass`? Will it always only contain one class/word?

Comment: Is `TheHTMLBlue` etc actually a variable, or some kind of pseudocode example?

Comment: @FelixKling: TheClass is a long string of CSS definitions that depends on the element I'm getting the value from. But the string will always contain the name of one of the colors I included in the code.

Comment: Use an array, or use a different approach entirely (why do you need to do this at all?).

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: it's a variable name; I use PolishNotation.

Comment: @frenchie If you post the contents of the vars like `TheHTMLBlue`, we might be able to suggest something other than the `if` chain.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: that's not where the issue is.

Comment: There really is no issue.  The code you've posted works fine, reads well, and achieves the task.  From what I understand, you're simply looking for ways to write it differently.  Michael is saying that we need to know _exactly_ what the code is doing for us to suggest ways to refactor it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example how the code could be written shorter (but not necessarily more efficient) with a regular expression:

```
var html = {
   'Blue': TheHTMLBlue,
   'White': TheHTMLWhite,
   // ...
};

var match = TheClass.match(/Blue|White|Green|Brown/);
// also possible:
// var match = TheClass.match(RegExp(Object.keys(html).join('|'));
if (match) {
    TheHTML = html[match[0]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd put the class names and the values into a map, and iterate the map looking for a match.
[Here (jsfiddle)](http://goo.gl/DcppN)  is an example of how to do it this way.

```
var classToHtmlMap = {
    'Blue': TheHTMLBlue,
    'White': TheHTMLWhite,
    'Green': TheHTMLGreen,
    'Brown': TheHTMLBrown
}

var TheHTML;
var TheAjaxIndicator = $("#TheAjaxIndicator");
$.each(classToHtmlMap, function(key, value) {
    if(TheAjaxIndicator.hasClass(key)) {
        TheHTML = value;
            return false;
    }
});
```

By the way, this uses jQuery, but the method is the same, no matter how you do it.

Comment: Good idea. If a match was found you can `return false;` from the `$.each` callback to stop iterating over the remaining properties.

Comment: No, that's not what it's about; the class name isn't "Blue" or "White", it's a long string that contains several class names.

Comment: @frenchie - yes, that's why I used hasClass - it will determine if any of the element's classes match the desired class name - it doesn't match the whole list of classes as one long string.

Comment: @frenchie: So, is `Blue` part of a class **name** or is it its own class? That's independent from whether the element has multiple classes or not. I.e. does it look like `class="foo bar Blue"` or `class="foo bar baBluez"`? Even if it is the latter, you can replace `TheAjaxIndicator.hasClass(key)` with `TheAjaxIndicator.prop('class').indexOf(key) > -1`. The approach is still a good one.

Comment: @FelixKling - thanks, yes - I updated the code to add the "return false;" - much more efficient - thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you follow variable naming conventions where local variables use `pascalCase` rather than `TitleCase`. I digress.

Having `if` statements in your code will not negatively impact performance at all - this is 2013 and we have JIT scripting engines. Your code is very readable as well - I see no reason to change it (other than the naming convention). But you could use a `switch` statement **but only if** the `class` attribute is a single value:

```
switch( theAjaxIndicator.prop('class') ) {
    case "Blue" : theHTML = theHTMLBlue;  break;
    case "White": theHTML = theHTMLWhite; break;
    case "Green": theHTML = theHTMLGreen; break;
    case "Brown": theHTML = theHTMLBrown; break;
}
```

If you want to have some fun, and to confuse anyone who tries to read your code, you could creatively use `eval`, like so:

```
eval('theHTML = theHTML' + theAjaxIndicator.prop('class') + ';');
```

But this code would be slower as it forces a script recompilation. I don't know how JIT works in this case.

Comment: The class name isn't "Blue" or "White"; the class name just contains these values inside it.

Comment: @MattBall I know it isn't equivalent, but I did state my requisite assumption about the `class` attribute containing only one value.

Comment: @frenchie if it contains a value rather than equalling a value, then you'll have to use your original code then.